# Bootstrap 4 Find Selected Table Row Index

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 table that is populated with JSON data. I am trying to determine the index of the row the user clicks. Can someone help me with finding the selected row. I've looked at examples that just do not seem to work for me when I try them.

When I run the code:
var rows = $table.find("tr") creates the following array.

[image]

After that I just cannot figure out how to get the index of the selected row. Can someone help me?

```
<table id="table" 
        class="table table-hover"
        data-checkbox-header="false"
        data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
            <th data-field="Artifact">Artifact</th>
            <th data-field="Actionee">Actionee</th>
            <th data-field="LastReviewDate">Last Review Date</th>
            <th data-field="DateReminderSent">Date Reminder Sent</th>
            <th data-field="ReviewInterval">Review Interval</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

var $table = $('#table')

// Creates an array of 
var rows = $table.find("tr");

rows.find("selected", function (e, row) {
    alert(row.index);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when Bootstrap 4 populates a table, it adds an attribute "data-index", which holds the row index value. Below is how to get the row index of a selected row for Bootstrap 4 table.

```
// Get the selected row. Should only be one row.
var selectedRow = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");

// Ensure length is one before checking the data-index.
if (selectedRow.length == 1) {
    selectedRowIndex = selectedRow[0].getAttribute("data-index")
}
```